How to use initramfs on raspberrypi cm4
base info
board：rpi cm4  
img：core-image-base-xx.wic.bz, build by yocto
     add u-boot(version:2022.01) support;    
     add Initial RAM filesystem and RAM disk (initramfs/initrd) support 
initramfs: core-image-base-initramfs-xx.bin,build by yocto  
yocto:      
  poky：kirkstone,     
  meta-openembedded：kirkstone,     
  meta-raspberrypi：nanbield

First, I burned the core-image-base-xx.wic.bz, the system can run normally. Then, I replaced the Image in boot with core-image-base-initramfs-xx.bin. The system still works, but initramfs does not run successfully, The mounted filesystems is the previous rootfs.
I refer to the network answer and modify cmdline.txt to "dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 root=/dev/ram0 rootfstype=ramfs rootwait debug". The kernel should have started normally, but the filesystems failed with logs as follows:
Waiting for removable media...
[    3.349085] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    3.349620] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
  30  29  28  27  26  25  24  23  22 21  20  19  18  17  16  15  14  13  12  11  10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0...
Mounted filesystems
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /run/media/boot-mmcblk0p1 type vfat (rw,relatime,gid=6,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on /run/media/root-mmcblk0p2 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
Available block devices
major minor  #blocks  name

   1        0       4096 ram0
   1        1       4096 ram1
   1        2       4096 ram2
   1        3       4096 ram3
   1        4       4096 ram4
   1        5       4096 ram5
   1        6       4096 ram6
   1        7       4096 ram7
   1        8       4096 ram8
   1        9       4096 ram9
   1       10       4096 ram10
   1       11       4096 ram11
   1       12       4096 ram12
   1       13       4096 ram13
   1       14       4096 ram14
   1       15       4096 ram15
 179        0   30535680 mmcblk0
 179        1     133120 mmcblk0p1
 179        2   14589952 mmcblk0p2
 179       32       4096 mmcblk0boot0
 179       64       4096 mmcblk0boot1
Cannot find rootfs.img file in /run/media/boot-mmcblk0p1 /run/media/root-mmcblk0p2 , dropping to a shell

-----append info----
root@raspberrypi4-64:/boot# ls -al
total 90308
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    16384 Jan  1  1970  .
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root root     4096 Sep 20 11:24  ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 69306880 May  9  2024  Image
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 May  8  2024 'System Volume Information'
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    54707 Apr  5  2011  bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    54751 Apr  5  2011  bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    55375 Apr  5  2011  bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    52158 Apr  5  2011  bcm2711-rpi-cm4s.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root      262 May  9  2024  boot.scr
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    52476 Apr  5  2011  bootcode.bin
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root       95 May  9  2024  cmdline.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    49656 Apr  5  2011  config.txt
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     7262 Apr  5  2011  fixup.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     5399 Apr  5  2011  fixup4.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     3171 Apr  5  2011  fixup4cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     8385 Apr  5  2011  fixup4db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     8387 Apr  5  2011  fixup4x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     3171 Apr  5  2011  fixup_cd.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    10230 Apr  5  2011  fixup_db.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    10232 Apr  5  2011  fixup_x.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   567672 Apr  5  2011  kernel8.img
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr  5  2011  overlays
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root        0 Apr  5  2011  rpi-bootfiles-20230509~buster.stamp
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2975616 Apr  5  2011  start.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2251392 Apr  5  2011  start4.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   805724 Apr  5  2011  start4cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3747688 Apr  5  2011  start4db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  2998888 Apr  5  2011  start4x.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   805724 Apr  5  2011  start_cd.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4819624 Apr  5  2011  start_db.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  3722504 Apr  5  2011  start_x.elf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    16384 Jan  1  1980  uboot.env
root@raspberrypi4-64:/boot# cat cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait debug
root@raspberrypi4-64:/boot# cat boot.scr
'V=h)%M▒▒▒▒֬▒Boot script▒fdt addr ${fdt_addr} && fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} Image
if test ! -e mmc 0:1 uboot.env; then saveenv; fi;
booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr}

